# How can I increase the number of simultaneous network connections using Play WS?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a scala application that uses Play WS (outside of a play app) to transfer millions of records to a REST API.  Currently, when the app and the API are both on the same machine I can transfer an average about 9 records per millisecond.  I'd like to increase that number by a factor of 10.  Is there a setting that will allow me to increase the number of simultaneous network connections Play WS will have in flight at once?

Comment: I'm not specifying  the execution context and not using Play so I'm guessing the scala global (unless Play WS makes it's own).

Comment: Ahh that's right, WS uses the play default always. In that case you should try increasing the thread pool size Play uses: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools#Highly-synchronous